# problems with bcrypt-ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bcrypt

I'm new to rails and am trying to write the part of an app that handles all the nasty account stuff that I can use for all my future apps (I wasn't able to find a boilerplate that did that for me.).

Anyways. I've got bcrypt installed and I'm trying to register a new user. I created a route in `routes.rb` for registration. I also added the installed `bcrypt-ruby` gem to my `Gemfile`. I copied the source from bcrypt-ruby.rubyforge.org and my code looks like this.

```
class RegisterController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @user = User.new(params[:user])
        @user.password = params[:password]
        @user.save!
    end
end
```

With my user model looking like this.

```
require 'bcrypt'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    # users.password_hash in the database is a :string
    include BCrypt

    def password
        @password ||= Password.new(password_hash)
    end

    def password=(new_password)
        @password = Password.create(new_password)
        self.password_hash = @password
    end
end
```

I've done a lot of different things to determine what the problem is. The error I get when I submit something to the register controller is

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `stringify_keys' for "a":String): app/controllers/register_controller.rb:3:in `create'
```

So here is my questions. What is `def password=(new_password)`, this syntax is foreign to me. What is `||=`. This syntax is also foreign to me. Why am I getting this error? Is there a boilerplate for rails I can use to save me this trouble and I can start coding?

Cheers and Thanks!

edit: Added view code

```
<%= form_tag("/register#create", method: "post") do %>
 <p><%= text_field_tag(:user) %></p>
 <p><%= text_field_tag(:password) %></p>
 <p> <%= submit_tag("Register") %></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `def password=(new_password)`

   In Ruby, all the things you normally think of as operators (`+`, `-`, `=`, etc) are implemented as methods and you can do the same thing for your own methods. That's what this is: just a method for `password=`. That means anytime some other code calls `user.password =`, it's really calling this method.
2. `||=`

   This is essentially saying "return this user instance's password, but create one first if it doesn't exist". If `user.password` is there, it just returns that; otherwise, it creates a new `Password` and returns that.
3. I'm not sure why you're getting this error, but my guess is that `params[:user]` isn't what it's supposed to be. (Is it a string, instead of a hash?) The error is complaining that it can't process your params, so have a look at what `params[:user]` is. It should look something like this: `{ password: 'password' }`
4. Absolutely, there's no reason for you to implement this. [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) is a widely used authentication gem that will do all of this (and much, much more) for you. You could also use ActiveRecord's [`has_secure_password`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods/has_secure_password) feature, which also uses BCrypt, but that also requires some setup work and is much less flexible than Devise.

Comment: thanks. devise says 'if you're making your first rails app we recommend not using devise', but I'll still check it out.

When I do a render :text => params[:user] for the function It outputs whatever I put in the password textfield, as I expected. Does that help?

Do I have to do something special to use the user model?

Comment: That's definitely not the right `params` then. You need it to be a *hash* (key-value pairing) that includes the password, not just the password itself: `{ password: 'abcdefg' }`. You'll have to post your view code so I can take a look.

Comment: Oh that will definitely explain it then. My view is just a dumby view I whipped up myself since bcrypt-ruby doesn't say anything. Ill edit my origin post with the view

Comment: How can I pass the key-value pair? I don't understand what the point is.